# Rails 4 + Devise: how to sanitize multiple new parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, attributes, strong-parameters

Being fairly new to Rails, I am learning how to implement Devise.

To do so, I am following [this Site Point tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/) by Ilya Bodrov-Krukowski, from March 26, 2015.

One of the things the tutorial teaches is how to create a registration form with an additional field: `name`.

After updating the relevant view, the author explains the following:

> If you are using Rails with strong_params (which are enabled in Rails
>   4 by default), one more step is needed:
>   the `:name` attribute has to be whitelisted.

and he recommends this code to do so:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
end
```

This is working just fine... but my problem is that I want to add more than one new field to the registration form.

Indeed, I want my registration form to require users to type in their `first_name`, `last_name` and `company_name`.

I updated my view and I do get the right fields in the form.

However, so far, I have not been able to whitelist these three attributes.

I tried to do:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name, :last_name, :company_name
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :first_name, :last_name, :company_name
    end
```

But when I do so, I get an `unexpected ","` error.

I also tried:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company_name) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company_name) }
end
```

But I am afraid this is now **REPLACING** the default Devise attributes (email, password and password confirmation — and maybe some other attributes I am forgetting) instead of simply **ADDING** my new attributes to the list.

So, my question is: how can I whitelist `first_name`, `last_name` and `company_name` without overriding Devise default attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting square brackets around the array of items you're adding, and  using it with a `keys:` key and `permit` instead of `for`:

[https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters [4.2.x 4.3.x](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :company_name])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :company_name])
end
```

---

The shovel operator `<<` adds a single item only to an array, which is why `devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name, :last_name, :company_name` gives you an error, since you're passing it 3 arguments, not one.

The `+` operator adds two arrays together, which is what I've done in the snippet above.

Personally though, I'd just be using the last example you gave (passing in a block) and manually including all the fields you want, including devise's defaults, if you're using them.

UPDATE: In your comment, you asked: "do you know where I can find a list — of Devise's defaults parameters?"

They're defined in the github repo here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L83-L92

And here's the relevant code:

```
def attributes_for(kind)
  case kind
  when :sign_in
    auth_keys + [:password, :remember_me]
  when :sign_up
    auth_keys + [:password, :password_confirmation]
  when :account_update
    auth_keys + [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
  end
end
```

So, it's your `auth_keys` (usually email or username or whatever you've configured there) plus  `password` and `password_confirmation`.

But devise's defaults are actually besides the point. You're deciding what parameters you want/need to allow through for your own sign up form, and for your own account update action. If they happen to overlap with Devise's defaults, fine, and if they don't, that's absolutely fine too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation is very clear. By chance, do you have a list — or do you know where I can find a list — of Devise's defaults parameters?